# Use of the using keyword in C#

Tags: c#

In my background in C++ I was a supporter of using the scope resolution operator, for example

```
class Foo
{
    std::list<int>  m_list;
    ...
}
```

for external libraries, to keep clear which library you were using.

Now in C# I don't know if there's a rule of thumb or a best practice to know which packages should be included via the using keyword and which classes should be fully qualified. I suppose that this can be a subjetive issue, but would like to know the most extended practices.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I pretty much *never* fully qualify names - I always use `using` directives instead.

If I need to use two names which clash, I'll give both of them aliases:

```
using WinFormsTextBox = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
using WebFormsTextBox = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
```

That rarely comes up though, in my experience.

I tend to make autogenerated code fully qualify everything though, just for simplicity and robustness.

Comment: Same rule for me, `use` everything in your own code, and aliases for clashes.

Comment: This is better, though it does make you have a WTF moment if you don't see the aliases before you start reading the code where they are used. If only referring to the two classes once in the class it might be easier if you just used fully qualified names.

Answer (score 3):

I think the saving grace in C# is the directives are fully constrained to the file you place them in. I use them whenever their use is clear for the code in the file and it helps readability of the code. Another team at my office doesn't use them at all - I think it's nuts but they came up with their own rules and are happy with them.

Comment: No use of `using`? That is mad.

Comment: where would you say it improves code readability? I mean, that's exactly the kind of rule of thumb I was looking for :-)

Comment: Wow, no using directives... I really don't want to see: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Guid, System.Guid> guidMap = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Guid, System.Guid>()` for a variable declaration!

Comment: I had it once... mainly because some unstable IDE was generating them instead of with using.

Answer (score 1):

Tend towards whatever makes the code more *readable* and **understandable**.

If the name may be ambiguous and their is no common "most likely case" then fully/partially qualifying to make this clear can be sensible even if this increases verbosity.

If confusion exists but one candidate is far more likely then qualify only in those cases where you do not use the most common case.
Common example is the use of System.Collection.X classes rather than the System.Collections.Generics versions (perhaps for back wards compatibility). In this case importing the generic namespace is fine and any non generic ones are fully qualified.
This makes it clear where you are using legacy code.

If you will be dealing with multiple clashes and the resulting full qualification would make you code extremely unreadable then it may make sense to use aliases to separate them out but you should be pretty averse to doing this since it renders the resulting code easier to *physically* read but harder to *conceptually* understand. 
You have injected an element of inconsistency with the wider world. this makes code snippets within the class harder to understand in isolation.
If you must do this consider alias names which make it very clear that these are aliases as an indication to readers that they should look at the using statements for confirmation of the real types.